# How can I modify this function to add an eventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a function for a modal that looks like this:

```
+(function () {
'use strict';

/**
 * @constructor
 */
var Modal = function (target) {
    this.$target = document.querySelector(target);
    this.$dismiss = this.$target.querySelectorAll('[data-dismiss="modal"]');
    this.$backdrop = null;
    this.isVisible = false;
};

Modal.prototype.toggle = function () {
    return this[!this.isVisible ? 'show' : 'hide']();
};

Modal.prototype.show = function () {
    if (this.isVisible) {
        return;
    }

    var me = this;

    this.isVisible = true;

    // Disable scrolling of content behind the modal
    document.body.classList.toggle('modal-open');

    this.escape();

    // Add close events
    for (var i = 0; i < this.$dismiss.length; i++) {
        this.$dismiss[i].addEventListener('click', this.hide.bind(this));
    }

    this.backdrop(function () {
        me.$target.style.display = 'block';
        me.$target.scrollTop = 0;
        me.$target.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);

        // Modal must be the focused element
        me.$target.focus();
    });
};

Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
    if (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (!this.isVisible) {
        return;
    }

    var me = this;

    this.isVisible = false;

    // Enable scrolling of content behind the modal
    document.body.classList.toggle('modal-open');

    this.escape();

    // Remove close events
    for (var i = 0; i < this.$dismiss.length; i++) {
        this.$dismiss[i].removeEventListener('click', this.hide.bind(this));
    }

    this.$target.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
    this.$target.style.display = 'none';
    this.backdrop();
};

Modal.prototype.backdrop = function (callback) {
    if (this.isVisible && !this.$backdrop) {
        // Create backdrop
        this.$backdrop = document.createElement('div');
        this.$backdrop.className = 'modal-backdrop fade';
        document.body.appendChild(this.$backdrop);

        // Backdrop fade in
        this.$backdrop.classList.add('in');
    } else {
        // Remove backdrop
        this.$backdrop.parentNode.removeChild(this.$backdrop);
        this.$backdrop = null;
    }

    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
};

Modal.prototype.keyDown = function (e) {
    this.isVisible && (e.keyCode === 27) && this.hide();
};

Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
    this.isVisible ?
        this.$target.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown.bind(this)) :
        this.$target.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyDown.bind(this));
};

Modal.init = function () {
    var modal,
        target,
        triggers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal]');

    // Attach click event to modal trigger elements
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
        triggers[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            target = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
            if (e) { e.preventDefault(); }
            modal = new Modal(target);
            modal.toggle();
        }, false);
    }
};

// Self initialization
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    Modal.init();
}, false);

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        Modal.init();
    }, 4000);
});
})();
```

Instead of calling Modal.init() via a setInterval like at the bottom, I would like to target the id of a link ("tab_button") and trigger Modal.init() when it's clicked. I thought I could add something like:

```
var tab_button = document.getElementById("tab_button");
if (tab_button != null) {
    tab_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log("Tab button was clicked");
        Modal.init();
    }, false);
}
```

but it doesn't trigger the log/call when it's clicked. Any ideas?

This is javascript running on a Ruby on Rails application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend just hooking up your click handler to the document so any click events will bubble up to be handled in one place.  Otherwise you may need to re-attach the click handler anytime you modify the contents of the page such as with AJAX.  For example, assuming you have a link with an id 'tab_button' like this:

```
<a href="..." id="tab_button">...</a>
```

You can add a click handler like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tab_button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Tab button was clicked');
  Modal.init();
});
```

Comment: Nice! So the console.log() triggers great, but for some reason Modal.init() isn't be called...Hmmmm.

Comment: Modal.init() is being called after logging it, but it's not popping up the modal so it must be something else. Definitely answered my initial question though.

Comment: adding a setTimeout allowed the function to wait a second for the AJAX on the page to swap out of the elements and it worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Comment: @lolcopter - If you change your Modal.init to use $(document).on('click', '[data-modal]', function(e) {}), the setTimeout should not be needed.